# Is my jQuery conflicting?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

HELP!

I'm building this site: http://armandwho.com/site using a custom WP theme.

I'm trying to add a fullscreen background video (http://codecanyon.net/item/easy-video-background/1365012) and can get it to work on this test site http://clickjoe.com (takes a minute to load) but NOT on the build site.

I see an error when loading the page via my Safari Inspector:

/site/#:232TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("body").video_background')

Can anyone tell right off what the issue might be?

UPDATE: The only thing I can find that varies when loading the build & test sites is that the file "http://clickjoe.com/flash/video.swf" loads but this file doesn't get loaded on the BUILD site and the calls are exactly the same. Something is preventing this file from loading?

Comment: I am seeing this error "TypeError: $("body").video_background is not a function"

Comment: Yes, that's the same error I'm getting. I've put this in the header.php as required:

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/modernizr.custom.26584.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/video_background.min.js"></script>

Comment: Is that htm5 tag appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

First, you include jQuery 1.6.2:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

This sets up 1.6.2's `jQuery` and `$` objects. Then you include the `video_background` plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/video_background.min.js"></script>
```

This extends jQuery 1.6.2's `jQuery` and `$` objects to add the `video_background` method. Later, you include jQuery 1.7.2:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://armandwho.com/site/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
```

This overwrites **(!!!)** 1.6.2's `jQuery` and `$` objects, and the `video_background` method goes with them. Then, at the very end, you try to call `video_background`:

```
$("body").video_background({ /* ... */ });
```

...but `video_background` is already gone.

---

The solution would be to *only include one jQuery*, and include it before the `video_background` plugin.

Comment: It seems that Wordpress is loading the 1.7.2 version somehow. Is there anything I can edit in the code for video_background that will comply with the 1.7.2 version?

Comment: @Mojoe: You can remove the 1.6.2 version and move all of the plugins to after the 1.7.2 version.

Comment: Thanks @icktoofay - trying to figure out where Wordpress is calling that version...

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone knows how to convert my script that currently uses 1.6.2 to 1.7.2? Wordpress includes 1.7.2 automatically and I've rigged the site by renaming that file so WP doesn't see it and uses the 1.6.2 that I've called in the header.php file. This breaks the admin & I'd rather use 1.7.2 instead of loading an earlier version. The script I'm trying to get working is:'$("body").video_background({ format:"16:9",
    mp4:"video/AM.mp4" ,
    formatMobile:"16:9",
    mp4Mobile:"video/AM.mp4" ,
    loop:"true",
    autoplay:"true",
    muted:"true"
  });'

Comment: @Mojoe: The video background plugin should work just fine with 1.7.2; 1.7.2 is mostly backwards-compatible and the video background plugin doesn't use anything that changed as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code in the console after page load, and it works...:

```
$("body").video_background({ format:"16:9",
    mp4:"video/AM.mp4" ,
    formatMobile:"16:9",
    mp4Mobile:"video/AM.mp4" ,
    loop:"true",
    autoplay:"true",
    muted:"true"
  });
```

The `jQuery(document).ready();` handler is firing (you get an error), I just can't figure out why.  There are a ton of scripts on this page, it is likely conflicting.

Maybe the video_background javascript file hasn't loaded correctly when the ready() handler fires?

You could try removing other scripts one by one until you figure out which one is the problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I got it to work by inserting your code in the console. Now to figure out where the conflict is...